# Filemaker with Html table layout

Tags: filemaker

I'm designing a form layout in FileMaker, and I'm spending a ton of time just trying to get all the controls in the right spot. Is there some way of doing a table layout? I just want to say "this control is in this cell" and let the table take care of all the formatting. Instead of having to set the position on each object just right.

**What I Have**

A form with a bunch of fields, organized in a table manner, i.e., rows and columns.

Example:

[image]

**What I Want**

To not have to specify the exact position of each individual control. Every time one element moves or needs to resize, it ends up screwing up the entire row, column, or "table", and I end up needing to move every field individually accordingly.

Is there a better way to organize fields in a form like this so that I don't have to manipulate the position and width of every "cell" in a row or column individually?

Comment: "*I'm having trouble finding the right way to word this question*" Indeed you are, and your question is not clear. There are no "cells" in Filemaker.  A layout can be either in Form view (showing one record at a a time), or in List view (showing multiple records as a vertical list), or in Table view  (a simplified List view simulating a spreadsheet). And I am not at all sure what you mean by "controls".

Comment: I want my form to have a rows and columns for field entry, I don't want to have to specify every single position of every element and align them perfectly. like `<table> <tr> <td> My Control </td> </tr> </table>`. Obviously I'm not working with markup, but it's really frustrating to have to specify each elements exact position and i was wondering if there's some other way.

Comment: You need to provide more detail. As I said, the Form view shows one record at a time - so you should not have rows and columns (unless you want to enter data as related records in another table - in which case you should be using a *portal*). -- P.S. The HTML terminology is not helpful, least of all to you. You need to adopt the Filemaker paradigm.

Comment: does my edit help at all?

Comment: Just barely. Are all those fields attributes of a single *object* (with that object being what a single record in your table represents? If yes, and you just want to control the placement of the fields (and other layout objects) on the layout in a more convenient way, then read: http://www.filemaker.com/help/13/fmp/en/html/edit_layout.10.66.html#1030136 Otherwise you need to rethink your strategy.  -- P.S. How come a single object has totals?

Comment: Okay, I guess what I want to do is group either the rows or columns together, so it's a bit easier to work with them as a group instead of doing each one. Not exactly what I wanted, but an improvement. Thanks! (the names of the fields were not designed by me, but "total" does actually make sense in this case. (it's a calculation on the single record))

Comment: Good. Just FYI, your question is totally off-topic for SO. You should join one of the Filemaker community forums.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is made easier with the use of the Inspector in layout mode. In particular, the controls in the "Arrange & Align" section on the "Position" tab of the inspector.

For example, you can quickly select all fields on the same "row" and align them to the top and make them the same height and width as needed.

If you are using FM 13, you may also want to make use of styles to make it easier to set the same formatting quickly across similar objects.

Comment: You can also try "Snap to Grid" and "Snap to Guides". Both could be found under "View" menu.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a web developer you might want to experiment using the WebViewer. You can use Javascript for creating a nice table. Then you can interact with that table through calling a script in FileMaker.

Or just stick to a portal like Michael.Hor recommended.